# C++ prevent access to a temporary

Tags: c++

I am working on a class that acts like a `std::variant`, in that, it stores another object using a union along with an error code. Like `std::variant`, there is a `get_if()` function that can be used to access to the object in the class. So something like this

```
template<typename T>
class result final 
{
    ...
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr T const *
    get_if() const noexcept
    {
        if (details::result_type::contains_t == m_which) {
            return &m_t;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
    ...
};
```

Now... suppose you have a function that returns an object using this class like this:

```
[[nodiscard]] static bsl::result<example_implementation>
make(bsl::int32 const answer) noexcept
{
    constexpr bsl::int32 valid_answer{42};

    if (answer == valid_answer) {
        return {bsl::in_place, valid_answer};
    }

    return {bsl::errc_failure, bsl::here()};
}
```

All of this works great. The problem that I cam concerned about is if the user does something like this:

```
if (auto const impl = example_implementation::make(valid_answer).get_if()) {
    example_bind_apis_type enforced_impl{*impl};

    if (enforced_impl.member_func_example(valid_answer)) {
        bsl::print("success\n");
    }

    if (!enforced_impl.member_func_example(invalid_answer)) {
        bsl::print("success\n");
    }
}
else {
    bsl::print("failure\n");
}
```

In the example above, the user is creating an example_implementation, and then using `get_if()` to get a pointer to the object wrapped by the result object. That pointer is then dereferenced and used. ASAN detects that the stack was used after destruction of an object, which is due to the fact that the "if" statement created a temporary result object, and then returned a pointer to something inside that temporary, which is deleted after the call to `get_if()`. This is similar to an issue with `QString` that I remember years ago, when people would get a pointer to the C style string inside the `QString` from a temporary.

Is there a way, in C++ to prevent the user from being able to call `get_if()` on a temporary like this? I tried reference qualifying `get_if()`, but that doesn't seem to work as the make function above returns an lvalue, not an rvalue (even though RVO will likely remove the copy). All I want to do is prevent the user from making this mistake accidentally.

**Update:**
As stated in the comments, make() is returning an rvalue, not an lvalue as I stated above, so a ref qualifier should work.

Comment: `void foo() & { ... }` and `void foo() && = delete;` to remove a method when used on a temporary?

Comment: _the `make` function above returns an lvalue, not an rvalue_ — I don't get it. `Make` returns by value, it's call should be an rvalue expression.

Comment: Your both right. Originally that's what I though too... it should be an rvalue, but when the ref-qualifier didn't work, my brain went sideways. I was missing the extra prototype to delete the rvalue reference qualifier. I only added the lvalue reference qualifier, which didn't do anything. Once I added the explicit delete, it started to do what I want. Frankly that is still a little confusion because I assumed that not adding the && version implicitly deleted it, but I guess not.

Comment: Another interesting question... why does `std::variant` not have this same qualification? Wouldn't it have the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use reference qualifier to your method:

```
template<typename T>
class result final 
{
    // ...
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr T const* get_if() const & noexcept;

    constexpr void get_if() && noexcept = delete;

    // ...
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a80053832c37420)

Comment: Yup... this works. I wonder why you need to explicitly delete the rvalue version. I assumed that by not providing this, it would implicitly delete this as it was not provided.

Comment: @RianQuinn I don't see a reason for deleted `&&`-qualified overload either. In this demo, it works as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/Ve9YSw. What is your compiler?

Comment: @RianQuinn The other overload is `const &` qualified. An rvalue can be bound to a `const &`...

Comment: but not a non-`const` `&` as in @DanielLangr's example

Comment: Ah... that makes sense. The compiler is allowed to us const & when it could not find &&. Once I deleted both && and const &&, it seems to work as expected. I am using clang 9.

Answer (score 0):

@Eljay in the comments above figured it out. You need to explicitly delete the rvalue reference qualified version of the function.

```
[[nodiscard]] constexpr T *
get_if() &noexcept
{
    if (details::result_type::contains_t == m_which) {
        return &m_t;   
    }

    return nullptr;
}

[[nodiscard]] constexpr T * get_if() && noexcept = delete;
```